# Why is mode always 1?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, statistics

One interesting concept that I am trying is calculating the mode (the number that appears the most for each line). When the there numerous modes, I would also like to print out only the lowest numbered mode value. I found a SO question about calculating the mode and trying to apply numerous answers, but all the answers I apply give me a value of one (I will show you).

As you can see, I tried several different approaches to calculate the mode line by line.

Any suggestions as to why the mode is always one? Thanks.

Update:
With the hand-feed code like the user below suggested the output is as follows:

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 2
item 3
item 2
maxitem 1
maxitem 2
Mode of list: 2
None
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 2
item 3
item 2
maxitem 1
maxitem 2
Mode of list: 2
None
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 2
item 3
item 2
maxitem 1
maxitem 2
Mode of list: 2
None
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 2
item 3
item 2
maxitem 1
maxitem 2
Mode of list: 2
None
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 2
item 3
item 2
maxitem 1
maxitem 2
Mode of list: 2
None
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 2
item 3
item 2
maxitem 1
maxitem 2
Mode of list: 2
None
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 2
item 3
item 2
maxitem 1
maxitem 2
Mode of list: 2
None
```

Since the mode of the list is actually 2, I believe that the mode function is working properly. I updated my code and output from the original names_list because I realized that the code and output did not match (Sorry about that).
So it is my understanding that the way in which I have names_list set up is incorrect to calculate the mode. I do not really understand exactly how that is and would appreciate any suggestions.

UPDATE2:

I took the advice of a user below to add `names_list = line.split(' ')` to my code in order to correctly parse the integers. That advice got me the correct values, but I would like to print out the smallest integers when there is more than one mode, and would still like to print the mode when there is only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where names_list is set, so I think you're omitting some code. Regardless, based on your output you are not splitting the line of the file into separate numbers.

That is, your list is [ "a string" ] instead of being [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6 ] a bunch of numbers.

The mode computation itself looks good. Try writing a test case, like this:

```
print_mode([1,2,3,2,3,2])
```

Feeding the list in by hand will help separate parsing errors from logic errors.

Comment: Please see my update, sir. It does not appear to be a logic error from the print_mode function, but a parsing error that I do not understand how to get a bunch of numbers like you said. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Then you probably want to split() the line of text. Depending on your python version, this may be the wrong link, but https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Comment: `names_list = names.split(' ')` may work, if names has "1 2 3" in it.

Comment: I applied split() and read the documentation (yes, that is the correct version of Python). However, when there are multiple modes of the same value, I would like to print out the smallest integer of those, and when all values only appear once, I would like to print out the smallest integer of those. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. I updated with the new code and new outputs. Thank you!

Comment: You can `sort()` a list so that the lowest appears first. But why is it called a `names_list` if it is full of integers? Are you changing to a new problem?

Comment: Also, you need to add a test case for the last item in the line, because I see newlines in your output. You should be stripping them off before you split.

Comment: I got the sorting thing done now and updated with it working. (If you see any immediate errors that could arise from the sorting, please explain as I just started learning Python). Thank you for the suggestion. Also, yes, I must change that list name because it is incorrect since there are integers and not strings for names. Also, can you please explain more about the test case for stripping the newlines like where that would be placed and if I would use something like .strip('\n')? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, `.strip('\n')` before doing anything else with line. Test cases are bits of test data or test scenarios you add to your testing code intended to handle a particular circumstance. For example, a line "1,2,3,3\n" should have "3" as the winner, but might print "1" if you don't strip newlines (since "3" and "3\n" are different strings).